# Responsive navigation bar design

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience

Is a horizontal sidebar considered unfavorable for user experience? Please provide insights and recommendations regarding the design of a sidebar as depicted in this screenshot. Are there any better alternatives or best practices to ensure an optimal user experience? Thank you!

This are the 3 screen shot for what i mean

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4W0K.png)

[when humberger menu click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEsFh.png)

[when sub menu show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxxjG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way your menu is proposed it will work, but I think there's good room for improvements. When we talk about user experience there are a few problems:

---

**1. Your menu is located far from the "thumb zone."**

The thumb zone represents the common areas that are easy to reach for most people. Normally this are includes right bottom and even center in some cases. You can [read about it on this article](https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/utilizing-the-thumb-zone-for-dropdowns-e579f0f9185a).

---

**2. The user has too many options.**

You are giving too many options to the user. Are all those options equally important? Try to identify the most important ones and give them the deserved highlights.

---

**3. Users aren't familiar with horizontal menus on mobile.**

If you don't have a clear reason for it, avoid creating a pattern that users aren't familiar with. It's preferable to stick with familiar patterns.

I highly recommend checking how big companies are dealing with those patterns. For instance, [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/), [Slack](https://slack.com/) and [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) all of them have big menus, but all of them use the sidebar approach. Take some inspiration from their mobile websites:

[image: Mobile menus example showing the sidebar usage on Slack, IBM and Stripe websites]